# Is the derivative of $ \ln f(x) $, where $f(x)$ is linear, the same for all $f(x)$?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

$\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)=\frac{{f(x)}'}{f(x)}$

Taking $\ f(x) $ as a linear $\ ax $ the result will always be $\frac{a}{ax} =\frac{1}{x}$

I found this confusion causing in the case of integrating, how would I know  what function to get back?

$\ln$ here stands for the natural logarithm.

Comment: $\ln(ax)=\ln a+\ln x=\text{constant}+\ln x$.

Comment: What is the question? Note that $\log (c f(x)) = \log x + \log f(x)$, so the derivative is insensitive to multiplication by positive scalars.

Comment: What's the problem? An antiderivative is defined up to an additive constant anyway.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify things, recall that $\log(ax)=\log(x)+\log(a)$ for $x>0$ and $a>0$.

The term $\log(a)$ is a constant and has $0$ derivative.

Hence, $$\frac{d}{dx}\log(ax)=\frac{d}{dx}\log(x)=\frac1x$$for all admissible $a$ and $x$.